# selecting variables with hierarchic preference

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple data from the same persons (column ID identical) but with different exam results. I want to extract for each person (unique ID) the exam with the highest frequency and the highest prevalence.

df:

```
day ID Rate Prevalence 
1 1234 3 Occasional 
2 1234 2 Frequent 
1 4567 2.5 Rare
2 7899 1.5 Abundant 
2 7899 4.5 Frequent
```

---

I was thinking to make a loop:

```
uniqueID <- unique(df$ID)
for (count in 1:lenght(uniqueID)){
 Curr_ID <- uniqueID[count]
 ID_set <- subset(df, ID==Curr_ID)
Prevalence <-
```

**Here are the problem I would like to choose in the ID_set for Prev with a hierarchic preferences and do not know how to do it : if "Abundant" set "Abundant", if no "Abundant" look for "Frequent" and if "Frequent" set "Frequent", if no "Frequent" look for "Occasional" and if "Occasionnal" set "Occasional" and so on **

I hope the problem is clear.

Comment: It would be usefull to create a minimal reproductible example as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "with the highest frequency"--do you mean 'with the highest value in column `Rate`'?

Comment: For your example, could you add to your question what your final desired output/result would look like? A final desired data table would be helpful. (For example, would you have row 1 have ID 1234 and `prevalence` of `Frequent` as this would highest in your hierarchy?)